# Muy baja prediccion con XGBOOST y Keras_TensorF

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

> hola amigos...  estoy intentando obtener una mayor prediccion pero solo obtengo un ~39 % me gustaria incrementar a un ~70% he probado muchos parametros con XGBOOST y Redes Neuronales Artificiales pero no lo consigo. el enfoque es supervisado no tengo experiencia con modelos no supervidados
> Ayuda por fa
> adjunto el enlace de los datos :
> https://mega.nz/file/M1lE1ABZ#cWgU3uWlqPmrXwPNQA-r3j44WTGXgNI6v4zZaSlNP5Q
> ...

[image: CM Prediccion]

```
    import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# data set  https://mega.nz/file/M1lE1ABZ#cWgU3uWlqPmrXwPNQA-r3j44WTGXgNI6v4zZaSlNP5Q
dataset = pd.read_csv('RNA_00_RST_F.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:11].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 11].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 0)

from xgboost import XGBClassifier
classifier = XGBClassifier(max_depth = 3, learning_rate = 0.01,  n_estimators = 300,
                           gamma=0.1)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#
y_pred  = classifier.predict(X_test)

# 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Alguien por favor con conocimientos superiores que me pueda ayudar.  Un MASTER O UN DIPLOMADO EN DATOS. UN MATEMATICO PURO... ALGUIEN QUE HECHE UN POCO DE LUZ... GRACIAS

Comment: Es posible que te ayude este link https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py